# How can I create two YouTube channels/pages under one YouTube account?

Tags: youtube

I really need to have multiple YouTube pages/channels under my YouTube account. I **don't** want to create another YouTube account.

How can I create a second YouTube pages/channel?

Comment: This would actually be an interesting feature. Tumblr currently has this feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have more channels under a single YouTube account currently. You have to create different accounts for each channel.

Answer (score 2):

The current answers are out of date.  Youtube now has a 'content manager' feature that allows you to manage multiple Youtube channels from a single Google account.  However, it does look like you need a Google account linked to a 'Youtube CMS Account' before you can do this, and I'm not sure how to do that just yet.

Anyway, rather than try to explain it, here's [a link to the Youtube help page](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guide.cs&guide=28127&topic=28332) about it.

---

**EDIT:** Ah, it looks like you have to be a Youtube partner to be eligible for a CMS account.  Bummer. =[

Answer (score 1):

In youtube, each user account is considered as a channel, so it is not possible to have multiple channels under one user account. You have to create another youtube account. You can login to multiple accounts and switch among them easily.